# "ip route get" shows wrong source IP address

Tags: linux, ip, routing

I have a machine with an interface which has two IP addresses:

```
inet 192.168.1.15/32 scope global eth0
inet 10.10.118.45/24 brd 10.10.118.255 scope global eth0:hosts4
```

If I execute for example `ip -s route get 8.8.8.8`, then according to this, egress packet will have a source IP address `10.10.118.45`:

```
8.8.8.8 via 10.10.118.254 dev eth0  src 10.10.118.45 
    cache  users 1 used 1
```

However, when I for example `ping` or `SSH` to `8.8.8.8`, then source IP is `192.168.1.15`:

```
15:19:38.092508 IP 192.168.1.15 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 9135, seq 2, length 64
15:19:38.097962 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.1.15: ICMP echo reply, id 9135, seq 2, length 64
```

What is the reason that in this case `ip route get` doesn't show the correct source IP address?

Comment: What's the output of `ip rule list`? And for each table listed, what is the output of `ip route list table $table`?

Comment: What does `ip route show to match 8.8.8.8` say ?

Comment: @Martin `ip route get` prints the result of the routing selection algorithm, and prints the source address from the `src` field of the matching routing table entry. However, an application can bind an address to the socket, which is then used instead as the source address in the IP packets. See [Source Address Selection](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-saddr-selection.html). Maybe your ping program does this? (There are several ping programs; from which package is yours?)

Answer (score 3):

A machine can only have one default gateway. You can use ping -i to pick which interface you want a packet to come from. From the information you've provided it appears that your default IP is 192.168.1.15. 10.10.118.45 appears to be an alias. Check your `/etc/networks`, `/etc/sysconfig/network`, as well as the interface configuration inside `/etc/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`

Here is a sample output of similar config.

```
[root@cp-rc ~]# ip route show
default via 192.185.130.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.9 metric 100
192.185.130.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.185.130.90 metric 100
[root@cp-rc ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.185.130.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth1
192.185.130.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Please read the [tour], it provides some useful information. If you have multline program output (or code) select the lines and then click `{}` for better readable text.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's possible that your `10.10.118.45/24` is dhcp address ? you can try to remove the static address